# Regex - ignore inside word + html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

trying to select the word "content" (using javascript) with my limited regex knowledge from the below:

```html
Here is content <p>content</p> content. Content contentpeople peoplecontent peoplecontentpeople
```

With the regex:

```js
([\S]*)content([\S]*)
```

This gets me "content" without the spaces but is also bringing back the P tag and "peoplecontent" - I only want if its not part of another word. I need to chain some NOTs together right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\b`, the [word boundary metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) i.e.

```
/\bcontent\b/g
```